# Access VBA: How to control element when it has focus

Tags: ms-access, button, vba

I'm trying to disable a button when it is clicked:

```
Private Sub submitButton_Click()

    Me.submitButton.Enabled = False
    If dataPath = "" Or skuPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter spreadsheet locations."
    Else

        Call importExcelData(dataPath, "data")
        Call importExcelData(skuPath, "skus")

        If validate = True Then
            Call generateReports
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

I'm getting a runtime error: "You can't disable a control while it has the focus".
Do you know a way around this?

Thanks!

Comment: you can move the focus to another control by using setFocus, maybe a hidden control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first set the focus to a different control.

That said, if you really have no other control to send the focus to (which I'd find hard to believe), there is a "workaround."  You can add a command button and set its TabStop property to False and its Transparent property to True and set the focus to that control.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me, the code still hits that hidden contol.  Any additional tips?

Comment: @MAW74656: There's not much else to say without knowing the specifics of your case.  The fix for this error is generally pretty straightforward.  If you are still having issues, I would suggest you post a separate question.  Link back to this question and explain what you tried and why this solution doesn't seem to be working for you.